# Can't get Delayed::Job to work with a very simple class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a problem using `Delayed::Job 2.1.4` on a very simple class, which is:

```
class C2dmJob < Struct.new(:msg)
  def perform
    # doing something
  end
end
```

At the begining I put this class at the `lib` directory but moved it after to the model directory for testing purposes. When running: `Delayed::Job.enqueue C2dmJob.new('foo')` I get the following entry stored inside the `Delayed::Job` table:

> 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:C2dmJob \nmsg: foo\n", last_error: nil,
>   run_at: "2011-07-21 10:56:58", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil,
>   locked_by: nil, created_at: "2011-07-21 10:56:58", updated_at:
>   "2011-07-21 10:56:58">

And the job fails with the following error message:

> [Worker(host:xxx pid:2660)] C2dmJob failed with
>   NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You
>   might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while
>   evaluating nil.each - 1 failed attempts

What do you think is wrong? I suspect something related to serialization  but I have no clue what exactly!

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your job code listing?

Comment: with head of stacktrace please

Comment: The job filename is `c2dm_job.rb`. What do you mean by job code listing? The class that performs the job is `C2dmJob`. Ah you mean, the code inside perform? I have nothing inside it, just a `puts`(I removed the real code to test with the strict minimal code).

Comment: ok, code seems valid and doesn't include obvious errors. Probably the reason that Delay_job version 1.6.2 was out more than 2 years ago. can you try 2.1.4?

Comment: Oops, turns out I was already using 2.1.4. `1.6.2` was the version of `gem`.

Comment: did you have any other classes called the same "C2dmJob"?

Comment: The answer is yes! And I changed its name and now it works! Please, post this as an answer to this question with some explanation on why it failed! Thank you very much, I actually spent 3 hours on this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is the class names coincidence, DelayedJob is looking for **perform** method into another class with the same name

Comment: Ok. I still find it weird because at that time I had only **one** `C2dmJob` class. Does it cache the class location or something like that?

Comment: classes never cache in development mode, do you still have an issue?

Comment: file location does not matter

Comment: No that issue is fixed. Just trying to understand how it could possibly look for another class (that was removed), when there is actually only one copy of that class when I ran the job!

Comment: it can be your next question on stackoverflow, it's a big discussion here :)

Comment: Yep, could be :). But I think I just needed to restart the `jobs:work` rake task so that it can be aware of the modifications.